# Edit meta tag in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am receiving data from get method URL & based on that I want to change meta tag of title & image.

```html
<meta property="og:title" content="new title" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/thumb.jpg" />
```

I want this meta detail & remove page's default meta data.

Comment: By which plugin are you generating the current meta tags?

Comment: Meta tags are not standard in Wordpress so they are either being added by a plugin or theme. You will need to find it to be able to change the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below hook and function to remove meta tags.

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'insert_in_head', 11 ); 
function insert_in_head(){
 echo '<meta property="og:title" content="new title tag" />';
 echo '<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/big.jpg" />';
}
```